# Absolute Convergence of Improper Integral of sinx/(e^x-e^(-x))

Tags: improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

I want to prove absolute convergence of improper integral ;

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\text{sin}x}{e^x-e^{-x}} dx.
\end{equation}

But I couldn't prove this. (I don't have to calcurate the value. I only have to prove absolute convergence.)

My attempt is as follows.

$
\left|
\dfrac{\text{sin}x}{e^x-e^{-x}}
\right|
\leqq
\dfrac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}} \\
\int_{\epsilon}^N \dfrac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}} dx
=_{(t=e^x)} 
\int_{e^{\epsilon}}^{e^N} \dfrac{1}{t^2-1} dt
=
\dfrac{1}{2} 
\left[ 
\text{ln} \left| \dfrac{t-1}{t+1} \right|
\right]^{e^{N}}_{e^{\epsilon}}
$

I want to let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $N \rightarrow \infty.$

However, if I let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$,
$
\text{ln} \left| \dfrac{e^{\epsilon}-1}{e^{\epsilon}+1} \right| \rightarrow - \infty
$

I would like you to give me any ideas or hints to prove absolute convergence of

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\text{sin}x}{e^x-e^{-x}} dx.
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: use $\sin x < x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @Gary I am having difficulty in calculating ∫_0^∞ x/(e^x-e^{-x}) dx. What method should I use?

Comment: Show that the integrand is bounded near $x=0$ and that it tends to $0$ very fast at $+\infty$.

Comment: To show absolute convergence, you do not have to compute the exact value of that integral. Just show that it is finite.

Comment: @Gary $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}} = \dfrac{1}{2}, \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}} = 0.$ But then, can I say that the integral converges?

Comment: You need to show that convergence to $0$ is fast enough. For example $\frac{1}{x}$ tends to zero at $+\infty$ yet $\int_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{x}dx}$ diverges.

Answer (score 4):

The integrand is $$\frac 12 \sin (x) \text{csch}(x)$$ Composing Taylor series, you have
$$\frac 12 \sin (x) \text{csch}(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ so, no problem around $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$ we have
$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{e^{x/2}}$$

because for $x>1$
$$e^x-e^{-x}>e^{x/2}$$

thus
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{e^x-e^{-x}} \,dx\le \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{x/2}} $$
as the last integral converges, the given integral converges at $+\infty$.

It converges at $x=0$ as proved above by Mr.Claude Leibovici:

as $$\frac{\sin (x)}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
the integral converges at $x=0$ either.

Its value is $\frac{1}{4} \pi  \tanh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

Thanks to contributor Gary for the useful collaboration.

Comment: It is the other way around: $e^x -e^{-x} <e^x$.

Comment: @Gary thank you!

Comment: Of course, this makes your argument incorrect.

Comment: @Gary thank you again!

Comment: Your new inequality is not true for all positive $x$. Note that $e^x -e^{-x}=2 \sinh x$ is zero at the origin and $e^{x/2}$ is at least $1$ for non-negative $x$. You have to deal with the removable singularity of the original integrand at $x=0$ somewhere in your proof.

Comment: @Gary Thank you$^2$! You deserved a mention...